# How to add a "processing" gif to a Modal Dialog?

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog, image-display

I am popping up a Modal Dialog using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`.  From the time that the modal pops up until the controls render on the page there is sometimes a bit of a lag.

What I would like to do it add some sort of animated gif to show that it is processing.  Can anyone recommend an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the SPLongOperation, a small example:

```
SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);

operation.Begin();

// long running code here ...
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

operation.End("http://www.nu.nl");
```